# How to query Chart of Accounts when connecting to NetSuite using ODBC?

Tags: odbc, netsuite

Can I query chart of accounts data when connecting with ODBC? I can't find the table with this information. I found an object called "Accounts" in Connect Browser but when I run the following query it's complaining object doesn't exist.  I'm connecting to NetSuite2.com

```
SELECT * FROM Account

ERROR [42S02] [NetSuite][ODBC 32bit driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Base table:Accounts
```

Answer (score 0):

the query that you want to use is

```
select * from account
```

if you are using the analytics schema, but if you are using the connect schema, the query is

```
select * from accounts
```

You can tell if you're using the connect schema or the analytics schema by checking your connection string.  If the SDSN variable in the connection string is `Netsuite2.com`, you are using the analytics schema.  If the SDSN variable i the connection string is `Netsuite.com`, you are using the connect schema.

To see what tables / columns are available using the analytics schema, you can use this site:

https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2021_1/analytics/record/account.html

It's not great at navigation but can help if you know what you're looking for.